# How do i rotate a cube using command buttons in android?

Tags: android, opengl-es

i have created a cube using openGL es in android sdk. now i have put buttons to rotate the cube in left and right directions. how do i call gl.glRotatef in click events of the buttons(created in CubeActivity class) ??

Answer (score 0):

If you are using openGL ES 2.0, then you can't really, as it's not part of the API.  If you are using openGL ES 1.x, then what you are looking for is `onTouchEvent`: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29

Just track where the finger is when it touches the screen, and you can rotate based on that until the user releases their finger from the screen.